# plunker Error in preview for Angular Js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, plunker

I have been trying to figure this out and wanted to see if I'm missing something, I am trying to learn angular Js on plunker and all of a sudden I'm getting this error, i have references to Jquery and i thought earlier it was the order of the link files so moved Jquery to the top in index.html and now that error is gone but I'm getting a blank page with the following error. Can someone point out why I'm getting this still? I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 't.data.match(/at\-share\-bookmarklet\:(.+?)$/)')
```

[Plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/R9uPop40htRkhmq1NiGx?p=preview)

Comment: two controllers of same name??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic part is that you have two controllers named `StoreController` in your app.js:

```
app.controller('StoreController', function() {
  this.products = produce;
});

app.controller('StoreController', function() {
   this.tab = 1;

   this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
     this.tab = setTab;
   };

   this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
     return this.tab === checkTab;
   };

});
```

Rename the latter one (to `PanelController` I guess, based on the other stuff you have written in your plunker) and no more a blank screen.

What you encountered is that your latter `StoreController` overwrote your first one, thus making things seem broken, because there was no `products` variable in your latter controller.